# Show that the quotient of the Heisenberg Group with its center is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to show that the quotient of the Heisenberg group with it's own center, H/Z(H), is abelian. I'm not entirely sure what makes up this quotient group in the first place though... and I'm a little confused as to what quotients of matrix groups with multiplicative operators look like. Help, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

Show that

$$Z(H)=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}1&0&x\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\;;\;x\in\Bbb F\;\right\}$$

with $\;\Bbb F=\;$ the field over which the Heisenberg Group is defined.

Now just check the homomorphism

$$\phi:H\to \Bbb F\times\Bbb F\;,\;\;\phi\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}:=(a,c)$$

Another way, when $\;\Bbb F=\Bbb F_p\;,\;\;p=$ a prime: we have that $\;H\;$ is a non-abelian group of order $\;p^3\;$ and thus $\;H'=Z(H)\;$ both by the Class Equation (i.e., a finite $\;p-$ group has a non-trivial center), and because $\;G/Z(G)\;$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial for **any** group $\;G\;$.

Comment: How does showing this homomorphism prove that the quotient is abelian?

Comment: The homomorphism is surjective and $\;\Bbb F\times \Bbb F\;$ is an abelian group ...

Comment: @user3749105 It is written there (almost 10 years ago!) that $\;H'=Z(H)\;$ , so that the quotient is in fact $\;H/H'\;$ and thus of course abelian. What part isn't clear to you?

Comment: How does the fact that it was written here 10 years ago matter? Don't be arrogant!

Comment: @user3749105 First, good you erased the bad word you wrote before. Second, it is *not* about arrogance but about trying to remember what was done here. Third, now you understand how the quotient is abelian?

Comment: @user3749105 Well, it was afortunate to you, otherwise you could easily have been banned from this site.